# How to have my scripts interact with each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When my webpage has loaded it runs this script:

```
$(function() {
  return $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/get_script",
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
      return $("#myScript").html(data.myScript);
    }
  });
});
```

The script gets another script from my server (the `data.myScript` object). The new script that is added to my webpage looks like this:

```
<script>
  initScript = function() {
    return window.random_string = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
  };

  $(window).bind("popstate", 'hashchange', function() {
    return initScript();
  });

  window.random_string = null;
  initScript();
</script>
```

If the new script needs to make variables available for other scripts on the webpage I put them into a `window.my_variable` variable, but I'd like instead to be able to call e.g. `MyScript.random_string`.

I'd also like to be able to trigger the `initScript` function from other scripts. Like e.g. `MyScript.initScript()`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Firstly I'd suggest using `$.getScript` to load your JS code assuming you cannot embed it directly in a `<script>` tag. To solve your actual issue you just need to structure it in the manner you require. Simply create an object like `var MyScript = {};` then place all the functions and variables as properties within that object

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan but if you could put the above into an answer I'd be very thankfull.

Comment: Sure, I added it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I'd suggest using `$.getScript` to load your JS code assuming you cannot embed it directly in a `<script>` tag.

To solve your actual issue you just need to structure it in the manner you require. Simply create an object like `var MyScript = {};` then place all the functions and variables as properties within that object, something like this:

```js
$.getScript('/get_script', function() {
  // put logic to run after the script has loaded here...
  // note that you don't need your .html(data.myScript) any more
  
  MyScript.initScript();
  console.log(MyScript.random_string);
});

// in your external script:
var MyScript = {
  initScript = function() {
    this.random_string = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
  },
  random_string: null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, I'm trying out your solution, and I can see that the response payload from `'/get_script'`is indeed the script. But the `console.log(MyScript.random_string);` line isn't triggered, and nothing else I put int there is. I have also tried to call `MyScript.random_string;` from the browser console, but this raises `ReferenceError: MyScript is not defined`. Doesn't the external script need to get appended to the document somehow?